# .htacces Rewrite rule for hiding Magento store in sub-directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce site, and for secure reasons (I think) have it in a sub-directory like www.mysite.com/magento and not the root.

In order to view the site, "magento" needs to be in the link, but what I want is to be able to view my site by going to www.mysite.com without the "/magento" in the URL.

I have no great knowledge of .htaccess files but easily removed the index.php suffix but cannot remove the "/magento"

I keep getting 403, 404 & 500 errors when trying to do so.

I have tried numerous rewrite rules...for example;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^magento [NC] 
RewriteRule ^magento/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /magento/ 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /magento/index.php HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

These are some rules I found searching the web but none work.
Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if this is this even possible?

Cheers guys

Comment: Why don't you just set your DocumentRoot appropriately??

Comment: Definitely, adjust the virtual host.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the only thing you have on your site is Magento and everything  (including css, js etc) is in the Magento directory.
If that is correct you add the following rules to the .htaccess in the root folder of your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#uncomment the RewriteCond if you want to exclude certain files from this rule.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) magento/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

I think your solution is on the right track but its not quite what I need. Previously when I used www.mysite.com I got a 403 or 404 or 500 error but now with your code in the root htaccess file the url is redirected to www.mysite.com/magneto and the store is visible. But the "/magento" is still visible in the url.

Is there another way of trying to hide the "/magento"?

I really appreciate your response